# Entity Framework 5 - Code First Production Preparation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, production-environment

As part of our intended migration from Linq2Sql to Entity Framework, we have created a small EF model consisting of ten entities.  Because we are working with a legacy application we are using the 'code first' option and manually mapping our POCO objects to tables within the database.  **We do not want the Entity Framework code to update the database.**  I believe that the following is all I need to do to achieve this - I would appreciate confirmation as I was not sure whether the SetInitializer code should go here or perhaps in the Global.asax code.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<InboxDataContext>(null);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Subscribers.Mapping.DataSourceMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Subscribers.Mapping.SubscriberMap());
    ...
}
```

As part of this update, we have created a small test page (MVC controller and views) and added it to our main application project.  During development and testing this has worked well.  The only thing we did notice is that if we updated the underlying EF model, the initial page load seemed to take several minutes to render.  I assumed this was because EF had to rebuild its views and mappings to reflect the changes - to my disgrace, I didn't worry too much about this as a) I don't have a full understanding of how this works and b) it only seemed happened on model changes.

This morning we loaded this update to the production server for initial testing and this time the initial load problem became much worse - so much so in fact that the test page never loaded.

So, to get to my questions:

1. Is there anything else I should/should not be doing to prepare my
   application for production?
2. How can I improve the initial load performance?
3. How can I find out why the initial load on the production server
   never completes - I am not seeing any error messages?

I did try downloading the Entity Framework Power Tools and running the 'Generate Views' option on the derived DbContext class, but since I could only run this in the development environment I was not sure whether this would work when copied to the production server - it didn't appear to.

I should mention that the development environment contains just one hundred records in the main table and the production environment contains almost one million records (same schemas), again I wasn't sure if this would make any difference.

Any help advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The power tools generate views creates a class in your project, so as long as it is a compiled part of the app that you deploy to production, it should be working to help EF's cold-start load time.

Comment: Yes, I created the views and then redeployed the application - nothing more complex than an FTP copy.  This did not appear to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using an existing database then a better approach would be Model First. You can connect your Edmx to your current database and it will gather all the required mappings as they currently stand. It then also generates the POCO classes and DbContext (with EF5, you have to do it manually in <5). Using this approach may cut down on initialisation time as your code wont have to create a model at runtime.

Give this a try, and it might solve all your problems (I believe they are all related).

Comment: We looked at this first, but we decided that we wanted to separate out the model from the underlying data store completely - hence the code first approach.  Whilst I appreciate that this might resolve the issue, I am reluctant to believe that the code first model can't support a very simplistic model of just 10 entity classes (at this stage anyway).  The only difference between development and production, as far as I know, is the number of records in the database - could this effect the EF start-up performance?

Comment: The only difference between Model first and Code first is how you create the model. In both cases a model is created, but with model first you do it directly (thus saving initialisation time) and in code first it's done at runtime. There's nothing you can do with Code first that you can't do in ModelFirst. No the number of records shouldn't make a difference as the model checks the schema, not the records. I would try a Model approach, it would take a few seconds to update a blank model from a database, and see if that helps.

Comment: As suggested and created the model from the existing database.  Unfortunately, I seem to have the same problem as before.  The application works fine on the local development web server, but hangs (or at least has been locked up for over 30 minutes) on the production server.  I'm not seeing any errors (either on the web site or in the event logs), but if I look at the Task Manager I can see that the w3wp.exe process for the web site is continually growing its memory usage.  I can only assume that the problem is common to both Model First and Code First.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is I'm doing something, or not doing something, stupid on the production installation - but am at a loss as to know where to look.

Comment: Once the 30 minutes is over does the application work normally? Do you have any seeding? It sounds like you're doing a very complex query or some such, like a join over a table with a few million records. Could you perhaps isolate where the issue is arising. Perhaps bring a backup of the production DB into dev and then debug to see where it's hanging.

Comment: Thank your for your continued support.  Last night, more out of desperation than strategic thinking, I created a new copy of the web application and upgraded it from MVC 3 to MVC 4 along with ASP.net Framework 4.5 (was 4.0).  It didn't change any code other than what was needed for the upgrade - mainly DLL references.  I deployed the site to the same web server and the Entity Framework test code runs correctly.  I have no idea why other than perhaps there was some underlying problem with one of the DLLs?  No error logs support this theory.  The same code still hangs the MVC 3 version when run.

Comment: Very odd. Well I'm glad you got it sorted.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that EF query is around 70% slower than the Linq2Sql variant - to query 1.7M rows EF:2.4 seconds, L2S: 1.4 seconds. Admittedly this is pretty much a straight port of the code and there might be some EF specific optimisation that are relevant, but would this be typical?  If I run the emitted SQL script from each method directly in SQL Server Management Studio I see similar performance differentials, i.e. the performance of EF appears, on the face of it anyway, to be related to the way it constructs its query.

Comment: There is always an overhead when using an ORM, however there shouldn't be one as great as when you've suggested. I would just check how you're recording the length of query execution though, as there are a lot of factors to take into account when checking on database execution times.

Comment: On the MVC controllers, I'm simply putting a Stopwatch() before and after the query (once it has been .ToList()).  In SSMS, I just looked at the execution times.  Both approaches correlated within a few milliseconds.  UPDATE: I have now ported more queries and it seems that the more complex the query, the better the EF performance.  Some queries that take 6 seconds in L2S are reduced to about 4.5 seconds in EF.  Perhaps a case of some you win, some you lose.  Thanks again for your help.